# Nodejs Call function of object from within function of that object

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the code below I am trying to call the function getCollection of the object DbModels from within a call to the getCollection function:

```
DbModels.prototype.addUser = function(Users, callback) { 
this.getCollection("seq", function(error, seq_collection) {
  if( error ) callback(error)
      else {
  var ID = seq_collection.find({_id: 'Users'}, {'seq': 1});
  console.log("ID is: "+ID);
  console.log(this.parent);
      this.getCollection("Users", function(error, sel_collection) {....
```

However, this is not working, because this is referring to the first getCollection. How can I call the getCollection function from within the call to the get Collection?

I already tries this.parent, but that doesn't do the trick.

Thanks!

Comment: I've never used node, but have you tried arguments.callee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

store this to a variable beforehand:

```
DbModels.prototype.addUser = function(Users, callback) { 

var self = this;

this.getCollection("seq", function(error, seq_collection) {
  if( error ) callback(error)
      else {
  var ID = seq_collection.find({_id: 'Users'}, {'seq': 1});
  console.log("ID is: "+ID);
  console.log(this.parent);

      self.getCollection("Users", function(error, sel_collection) {....
```

Comment: That seems to call the function indeed, thanks. However now I get the following error:

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Any clues why?

Comment: not sure, i just noticed that you are assigning the call to find to a variable, instead of handling with a function, as in `seq_collection.find({_id:'Users'},function(err,element){  ... rest })`